# Can I recover an NVME M.2 PCIe drive that shows 0 bytes available?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, pci-express

I have an MSI B150 PC Mate MB that I used an M.2 adapter to install a NVME M.2 drive in the PCIex16 slot. Worked great, installed Windows, booted several times. Then I plugged in the old Sata HDD (had a Windows install on it) and was going to use it as a data drive. The MSI bios then "Fixed" the boot when I started the machine and now no longer recognizes the NVME drive at all. In addition, Windows install sees 0 bytes free and 0 BYTES AVAILABLE and reports "Windows cannot be installed on this drive. I tried installing the drive in a laptop with a PCIe M.2 slot and running Windows set up and it also shows 0 bytes free and 0 bytes available. I am afraid this drive might be bricked. Anyone seen this before? I saw a recommendation to plug it into a board, power on and leaving in the bios for 30 minutes, unplug power for 30 seconds then repeat - trying this now. Any ideas on what to do here? RMA?

Comment: `The MSI bios then "Fixed" the boot` - this could mean that the BIOS was switched from UEFI mode back to compatibility mode. In compatibility mode the NVMe drive is not available for boot. Make sure your BIOS is running in UEFI mode.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Yes it is UEFI only mode, CSM is disabled. If I boot in another Windows system it also shows there 0 bytes for the size and I cannot initialize the disk.

Comment: Try a Linux live CD/DVD/USB-Stick. Often Linux is capable to access devices that are "lost" from a Windows perspective. If that does not work try what result you get if you insert the PCIex16 adapter without SSD. If it is also a disk if size 0 bytes then most likely the SSD is gone. Have you always grounded yourself before touching any PC component? Static discharge can destroy electronic devices.

Comment: I will try the Linux live, I have one here already. I didn't touch the SSD between working and not working, the only thing I did was plug in the SATA HDD, then the bios came up and told me it had "Fixed" the boot order. Well it fixed it alright.

Comment: Ultimate Boot CD does not see the drive at all. recommendations for live cd to try?